# reactstrap with typescript, define ambient module

Tags: typescript, reactstrap

I want to use `reactstrap` with typescript.

There are typings for these typings: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/reactstrap/index.d.ts

Reactstrap is availabe on page as `Reactstrap` global variable. I thought adding it in ambient module would be as simple as adding `react` and `react dom`

Here's my `global.d.ts`

```
import * as react from "react"
import * as react_dom from "react-dom"
import * as reactstrap from "reactstrap"

declare global {
    type React = typeof react
    type ReactDOM = typeof react_dom
    type Reactstrap = typeof reactstrap
}
```

I can use `React.Component` and jsx without importing, it's available globally. But i can't use `Reactstrap.Alert`, tsc says that`Reactstrap.Alert` is a type but used like a value.

I can manually add this string `export as namespace Reactstrap` in a d.ts file, but it looks like a hack, and this changes are not stored in my git repo. Is it possible to export all classes from one d.ts and put it into namespace of another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created file `_reactstrap.d.ts` next to `global.d.ts` with this content:

```
export * from "reactstrap"

export as namespace Reactstrap;
```

And modified `global.d.ts` as follows:

```
import * as react from "react"
import * as react_dom from "react-dom"
import * as reactstrap from "./_reactstrap"

declare global {
    type React = typeof react
    type ReactDOM = typeof react_dom
    type Reactstrap = typeof reactstrap
}
```